# Extracting data from a dynamic website using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web, dynamic, driver, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract the name of the participants and the number of modules completed in a CSV file from this website - https://learn.microsoft.com/training/challenges?id=f66f0d57-d644-44d1-9faf-112b18a0ef92

The below is my code, a few days back, I have written a code successfully, but later I tried to modify it and now nothing is working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Initialize the web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 

# URL of the website
url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/training/challenges?id=f66f0d57-d644-44d1-9faf-112b18a0ef92"
driver.get(url)

# Locate participant names and modules completed elements
participant_names = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".is-hidden-mobile.leaderboard-name")
modules_completed = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span")

# Extract data and store it in a list
data = []

for name, modules in zip(participant_names, modules_completed):
    data.append([name.text, modules.text])

# Define the CSV file name
csv_file_name = 'participants.csv'

# Write data to a CSV file
with open(csv_file_name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(['Participant Name', 'Modules Completed'])  # Write header
    csvwriter.writerows(data)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

print(f"Data has been scraped and saved to {csv_file_name}.")
```

This is the inspect element code for the name:

```
<span class="is-hidden-mobile leaderboard-name"><!---->Abhishek Kumar<!----></span>
```

For modules completed:

```
<span><!---->12/12<!----></span>
```

There is a pagination also, I was trying to include, but since due to errors, I removed it, but still the basic 1st page code is also not working.
Page code:

```
<button type="button" class="pagination-link is-current" data-page="1" aria-label="Page 1 of 4" aria-current="true">
                    1
                </button>
```

I would really appreciate if any code, or direction is given to complete this without errors.

The errors I encountered are the below

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\misss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\wspmlsa.py", line 17, in <module>
    participant_names = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".is-hidden-mobile.leaderboard-name")
  File "C:\Users\misss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 738, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\misss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\misss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".is-hidden-mobile.leaderboard-name"}
  (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.134); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65ADD7D12+55474]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AD477C2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65ABFE0EB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AC3EBAC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AC3ED2C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AC79F77]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AC5F19F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AC77EF2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AC5EF33]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AC33D41]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AC34F84]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65B13B762+3609346]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65B191A80+3962400]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65B189F0F+3930799]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65AE73CA6+694342]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AD52218]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AD4E484]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AD4E5B2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65AD3EE13]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFE68417344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFE6A2226B1+33]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is being hydrated in page from an API. Why don;t you scrape that API endpoint directly? You can find it in browser's Dev tools --> Network tab.

Here is one way to do it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get("https://learn.microsoft.com/api/challenges/f66f0d57-d644-44d1-9faf-112b18a0ef92/leaderboard?$top=1000&$skip=0&locale=en-gb", headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['results'])
print(df[['rank', 'score', 'userDisplayName']])
```

Result in terminal:

```
    rank    score   userDisplayName
0   1   12.0    _11KRISHNA VAMSI
1   2   12.0    ABDUL SAMAD KHAN
2   3   12.0    Abhishek Kumar
3   4   12.0    Aditya Srivastav
4   5   12.0    Akshay Gupta
5   6   12.0    Harshvardhan Nayakal
6   7   12.0    Khushi
7   8   12.0    Kreeti Jindal
8   9   12.0    Md Ibrahim Noman
9   10  12.0    MUKESH PAL
10  11  12.0    Patel Harsh Satishkumar
11  12  12.0    Prashant Dwivedi
12  13  12.0    Rudraraju Sriya
13  14  12.0    Sagar Chintamani
14  15  12.0    Samvarthika . C
15  16  12.0    Sandeep Kumar Patel
16  17  12.0    Shashank Kumar Srivastava
17  18  12.0    Shivanshu_Nigam
18  19  12.0    Smriti Tiwari
19  20  12.0    udit kumar singh
20  21  12.0    Viraj Bhutada
21  22  7.0     Akanksha Pal
22  23  2.0     Md Tawsif Mahmud Toha
23  24  0.0     Asritha mudunuri
24  25  0.0     Chandramani kumari
25  26  0.0     Kandukuri Jaswanth
26  27  0.0     Lilanjan Barman
27  28  0.0     Nelissa
28  29  0.0     Paresh Maheshwari
29  30  0.0     prachothan reddy kuthuru
30  31  0.0     Radhika Garg
31  32  0.0     Roopesh Ranjan
32  33  0.0     Roopesh Ranjan
33  34  0.0     sayyid hassan shaabani
34  35  0.0     SEELAM ALEXANDER
35  36  0.0     Tamilarasan S
36  37  0.0     Vashu Agarwal
```

You can explore that json response, maybe look at other data contained.

Requests documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), and for pandas docs, go [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked well for Page extraction, not sure about all other pages!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Initialize the web driver (choose the appropriate driver for your browser)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Use Chrome or other browsers you prefer

# URL of the website
url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/challenges?id=f66f0d57-d644-44d1-9faf-112b18a0ef92&wt.mc_id=studentamb_106710"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.is-hidden-mobile.leaderboard-name")))

# Locate participant names and modules completed elements
participant_names = driver.find_elements("css selector", "span.is-hidden-mobile.leaderboard-name")
modules_completed = driver.find_elements("css selector", "div.level-right.leaderboard-score-over-total span")

# Extract data and store it in a list
data = []

for name, modules in zip(participant_names, modules_completed):
    data.append([name.text, modules.text])

# Define the CSV file name
csv_file_name = 'participants.csv'

# Write data to a CSV file
with open(csv_file_name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(['Participant Name', 'Modules Completed'])  # Write header
    csvwriter.writerows(data)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

print(f"Data has been scraped and saved to {csv_file_name}.")
```

Shared this, so if you are facing issue with the basic code, this may help!